# GCC's linker --wrap will not wrap over static library function

Tags: c, unit-testing, gcc, linker, cmocka

I am trying to mock C functions using CMocka and GCC's `--wrap` linker option. So far this technique has worked well for mocking stdlib functions such as `fgets`, `popen`, `pclose`, etc.

However now I am trying to mock functions that are in a static library and this does not work as well. In fact the static library function is always called, even if I try to mock it using `--wrap`. I have managed to reproduce this in a foobar project.

Here is the source code of my very simple static lib:

**hello.h**

```
#ifndef HELLO_H
#define HELLO_H

void hello();
void world();

#endif /* HELLO_H */
```

**hello.c**

```
#include "hello.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void world()
{
    printf("world from lib\n");
}

void hello()
{
    printf("hello\n");
    world();
}
```

And here is the source code of my test program:

**tests.c**

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#include "cmocka.h"
#include "hello.h"


void __wrap_world(void)
{
    puts(mock_ptr_type(char*));
}

void test_hello(void **state)
{
    (void) state; /* unused */

    assert_int_equal(7, 1 + 2 * 3);

    will_return(__wrap_world, "world from tests\n");
    hello();
}

const struct CMUnitTest mytests[] = {
    cmocka_unit_test(test_hello),
};

int main(void)
{
    return cmocka_run_group_tests(mytests, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Finally, the linker line is as follows (I am using CMake so that's why it looks this weird), splitted on multiple lines for your eyes:

```
/usr/bin/cc \
  -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c99 \
  CMakeFiles/tests.dir/tests.c.o \
  -o tests -Wl,-rpath,/home/microjoe/cmake-fail/cmocka/build/src \
  -rdynamic -lgcov /home/microjoe/cmake-fail/cmocka/build/src/libcmocka.so \
  -Wl,--wrap,world \
  -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage \
  ../lib/libhello.a
```

And of course the tests output that shows that the wrap function was not called as expected:

```
[==========] Running 1 test(s).
[ RUN      ] test_hello
hello
world from lib
[  ERROR   ] --- __wrap_world() has remaining non-returned values.
/home/romain/cmake-fail/hello/tests/tests.c:23: note: remaining item was declared here

[  FAILED  ] test_hello
[==========] 1 test(s) run.
[  PASSED  ] 0 test(s).
[  FAILED  ] 1 test(s), listed below:
[  FAILED  ] test_hello

 1 FAILED TEST(S)
```

Comment: This was asked not that long ago. Basically the *compiler* resolves the function to its address, the linker never sees it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43183060/how-to-wrap-existing-function-in-c

Comment: Ok so the problem is that in the same object file the wrap hack does not work. The solution to my problem is to use __attribute__((weak)) before the declaration (and not implementation) of void world(void) in the tests. Too bad I cannot write an answer to myself in order to clarify this comment.

Comment: you can write the answer to the duplicate target!

Comment: the point in reducing duplicates is that there is only a *single* place where the good answers concentrate. Frankly I didn't even *know* about *`weaken`*  at all before I found that *duplicate target*. It might have been that this question would have been resolved with "OK, it can't be done".

Comment: Thank you, I have added my answer in the other topic in your comment. I think the duplicate should link to the question in your comment.

Comment: I thought the first one is way better :?

Comment: It's got the picture detailing what works and what *doesn't*

Comment: Well I am in the duplicate hell now I guess. Should I backport my answer to this other thread that seems to lack my answer using __attribute__((weak))? Should one of the two threads be marked as duplicate then?

Comment: Well well :D good question. I can hammer them immediately. I think the deduplication has a point. I had answered this question before, and then thought this was a duplicate of that and ttried to google  and found *that* one that didn't tell how to fix... and only later found that which *would fix* :D

Comment: Though, the question is: can you *call the original one* with `__attribute__((weak))`?

Comment: I have tried it and it seems that there is no way to call the original one once overriden. Worse, if you override the symbol in one .o file then every .o file will use this new symbol. It means that if I want to mock only inside a single .c file I have to create two executable because of this global override of the weak symbol.